# Accord avec le mot "personne"

Tags: accord, genre

Le mot "personne" étant féminin, doit-on accorder le reste de la phrase au féminin ou en fonction du genre de la personne en question ?

Par exemple dira-t-on :

> Cette personne est choquée par cette situation

ou

> Cette personne est choqué par cette situation

En partant du principe que dans les deux exemples, la personne en question est un homme.

Comment: "Cette personne est choquée par cette situation", même si c'est un garçon, c'est la personne dont on parle, pas de son genre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En français, l'accord sémantique direct est très rare. L'accord a forcément une base syntaxique.

Par exemple, puisque le sujet « cette personne » est féminin singulier, le verbe est forcément féminin singulier. Peu importe que la personne soit un homme ou une femme.

> Cette personne est choquée.
> Une silhouette masculine est apparue.

Le nom central du sujet est féminin, donc le verbe est forcément féminin. L'adjective *masculine* est lui aussi au féminin puisque c'est un complément d'un nom féminin.

Il y a des cas où on peut faire un accord sémantique, mais il faut une base syntaxique : l'accord glisse, il n'est pas créé de toutes pièces.

> La majorité a voté.   (pas *<s>ont voté</s>)
> La majorité des participants a voté.
> La majorité des participants ont voté.   (correct mais moins courant)

Si le sujet est seulement « la majorité », le verbe est forcément au singulier. Avec un complément pluriel, le verbe est en général au singulier mais le pluriel est aussi possible.

L'accord sémantique est considéré en français comme un type de [syllepse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse). C'est une figure de style qui viole les règles de grammaire.

Il y a un cas particulier où l'on peut dire qu'on fait toujours l'accord sémantique : le pronom *vous* singulier du vouvoiement et le pronom *on* pluriel qui signifie *nous* en langage familier.

> Vous êtes belle.   (dit à une femme)
> On est sortis.

Je pense qu'il vaut mieux considérer que *vous* est (ici) un pronom singulier avec lequel on conjugue le verbe à la deuxième personne du pluriel (mais l'accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire *être* est au singulier), et de même *on* est ici un pronom pluriel avec lequel on conjugue le verbe à la troisième personne du singulier.

---

Summary: in French, agreement is almost exclusively syntactic. Pure semantic agreement is not possible. Verbs and adjectives agree with the grammatical gender and number of the noun.

There are a few cases where the agreement can shift from the grammatical subject to another noun, but there is always an explicit anchor. Even then, pure syntactic agreement is more common.

> La majorité a voté.   *(not *<s>ont voté</s>)*
> La majorité des participants a voté.
> La majorité des participants ont voté.   *(correct but less common)*

Comment: I don't think it's less common to use a plural after a "sujet collectif". Je pense que la plupart des gens seront/sera d'accord avec moi.

Answer (score 4):

On accorde avec le sujet, pas ce qu'il représente. Pour que cela soit plus évident, c'est le même cas qu'avec "le peuple". On ne dit pas "Le peuple **ont** faim", mais bien "Le peuple a faim", même si le peuple représente plusieurs personnes.

Ici, il en est de même, on écrit donc bien:

> Cette personne est choqué**e** par cette situation

Answer (score 1):

Il est toutefois intéressant de noter que dans la phrase "personne n'est méchant", personne est accordé au masculin.

Comment: Dans ce cas-là, *personne* est un pronom, pas un nom commun. https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/personne

Comment: Ah, d'accord, merci pour l'éclairage !